# Unsure as to why toupper() is cutting off last letter in C

Tags: arrays, c, letter, toupper

So the goal of this program is to basically take a 26 letter 'key' in the terminal (through `argv[]`) and use its index's as a substitution guideline. So there are 2 inputs you enter in the terminal, one in the `argv[]` and one is just a plain `get_string()` input. The `argv[]` input will look like this: `./s YTNSHKVEFXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO` where `s` is the file name. And then the `get_string()` input will look like this: `plaintext:  HELLO`. (The input is `HELLO`). What the program will then do is loop through all the letters in the plaintext input and substitute its alphabetical index according to the index of the `argv[]` key. For example, `H` has an alphabetical index of `7` (where `a` = 0 and `z` = 25), so we look at the 7th index in the key `YTNSHKV(E)FXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO` which in this case is `E`. It does this for each letter in the input and we'll end up with the output `ciphertext: EHBBQ`. This is what it should look like in the terminal:

```
./s YTNSHKVEFXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO
plaintext:  HELLO
ciphertext: EHBBQ
```

But my output is `EHBB`, since it cuts off the last letter for some reason when I use `toupper()`.

And also, the uppercase and lowercase depends on the plaintext input, if the plaintext input was `hello, world` and the `argv[]` key was `YTNSHKVEFXRBAUQZCLWDMIPGJO`, the output would be `jrssb, ybwsp`, and if the input was `HellO, world` with the same key, the output would be `JrssB, ybwsp`.

I'm basically done with the problem, my program substitutes the plaintext given into the correct ciphertext based on the key that was inputted through the command line. Right now, say if the plaintext input was `HELLO`, and the key was `vchprzgjntlskfbdqwaxeuymoi` (all lowercase), then it should return `HELLO` and not `hello`. This is because my program puts all the letters in the command line key into an array of length 26 and I loop through all the plaintext letters and match it's ascii value (minus a certain number to get it into 0-25 index range) with the index in the key. So `E` has an alphabetical index of 4 so in this case my program would get lowercase `p`, but I need it to be `P`, so that's why I'm using `toupper()`.

When I use `tolower()`, everything worked fine, and once I started using `toupper()`, the last letter of the `ciphertext` is cut off for some reason. Here is my output before using `toupper()`:

```
ciphertext: EHBBQ
```

And here is my output after I use `toupper()`:

```
ciphertext: EHBB
```

Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    
    // Putting all the argv letters into an array called key
    char key[26]; // change 4 to 26
    for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) // change 4 to 26
    {
        key[i] = argv[1][i];
    }
    
    // Assigning array called ciphertext, the length of the inputted text, to hold cipertext chars
    char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)];
    
    // Looping through the inputted text, checking for upper and lower case letters
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {
        // The letter is lower case
        if (islower(plaintext[i]) != 0)
        {
            int asciiVal = plaintext[i] - 97; // Converting from ascii to decimal value and getting it into alphabetical index (0-25)
            char l = tolower(key[asciiVal]); // tolower() works properly
            //printf("%c", l);
            strncat(ciphertext, &l, 1); // Using strncat() to append the converted plaintext char to ciphertext
        }
        // The letter is uppercase
        else if (isupper(plaintext[i]) != 0)
        {
            int asciiVal = plaintext[i] - 65; // Converting from ascii to decimal value and getting it into alphabetical index (0-25)
            char u = toupper(key[asciiVal]);  // For some reason having this cuts off the last letter 
            strncat(ciphertext, &u, 1); // Using strncat() to append the converted plaintext char to ciphertext
        }
        // If its a space, comma, apostrophe, etc...
        else
        {
            strncat(ciphertext, &plaintext[i], 1);
        }
    }
    
    // prints out ciphertext output
    printf("ciphertext: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(plaintext); i++)
    {
        printf("%c", ciphertext[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("%c\n", ciphertext[1]);
    printf("%c\n", ciphertext[4]);
    //printf("%s\n", ciphertext);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm repeating this, but "char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)];" looks suspect to me.   I'd prefer to see "char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)+1];", with the +1 to accommodate the \0 that terminates the string.

Comment: At least: `char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)]` -> `char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext) + 1]`

Comment: Don't write `65`.  Instead, write `'A'`

Comment: `ciphertext` is uninitialized, so `strncat` is undefined behavior.  You need a null terminator, which isn't there when it's uninitialized.

Comment: Thank you guys, the `char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)+1];` worked Mark Lavin and Jabberwocky. I'm sorry I would have voted you guys as a "useful comment" but I don't see the button. Thanks again!

Comment: @SimerusM: Can you please confirm you are using `<cs50.h>`?

Comment: @chqrlie, yes I'm using <cs50.h>. Thank you for your help, your suggestions for improvement really helped.

Comment: @SimerusM: I am glad to help. You seem ready to drop the training wheels and use actual pointers a `char *` for which `string` is just a `typedef`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `strncat` function expects its first argument to be a null terminated string that it appends to.  You're calling it with `ciphertext` while it is uninitialized.  This means that you're reading unitialized memory, possibly reading past the end of the array, triggering [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to make `ciphertext` an empty string before you call `strncat` on it.  Also, you need to add 1 to the size of this array to account for the terminating null byte on the completed string to prevent writing off the end of it.

```
char ciphertext[strlen(plaintext)+1];
ciphertext[0] = 0;
```

Comment: Additional advice: `plaintext` needs to be free'd at the end of the program. This is the reason why `#define`-ing pointer types is not a good idea: it obscures the pointer.

Comment: @Yun: I'm afraid you are mistaken. `get_string()` does allocate memory but it is not the user's responsibility to free these allocated objects as the library registers an atexit function to perform the clean up. cf https://cs50.readthedocs.io/libraries/cs50/c/#c.get_string

Comment: @Yun: this library is indeed problematic to many regards. It is only fit for beginners that will benefit from not having to learn the arcane trap and pitfalls of `scanf()` and other input functions, but may acquire counter-productive habits. Most importantly, they will not learn about pointers, which is the most difficult concept to acquire in C.

Comment: @chqrlie Maybe you're right! I thought `get_string` was a user-defined function that was simply not given for brevity. Then again, nothing in the question refers to this third party library, for as far as I can see.

Comment: @Yun: the OP just confirmed the use of `<cs50.h>`. This library is quite popular and while it gives beginners a head start to write small programs solving concrete problems, some of their ideas seem counterproductive, such as hiding `char *` behind a typedef (`string`).

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks for the update. My first comment is then irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems in the code:

- you do not test the command line argument presence and length
- the array should be allocated with 1 extra byte for the null terminator and initialized as an empty string for `strncat()` to work properly.
- instead of hard coding ASCII values such as `97` and `65`, use character constants such as `'a'` and `'A'`
- `strncat()` is overkill for your purpose. You could just write `ciphertext[i] = l;` instead of `strncat(ciphertext, &l, 1)`
- `islower()` and `isupper()` are only defined for positive values of the type `unsigned char` and the special negative value `EOF`. You should cast `char` arguments as `(unsigned char)c` to avoid undefined behavior on non ASCII bytes on platforms where `char` happens to be a signed type.
- avoid redundant tests such as `islower(xxx) != 0`. It is more idiomatic to just write `if (islower(xxx))`

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[]) {
    // Testing the argument
    if (argc < 2 || strlen(argv[1]) != 26) {
        printf("invalid or missing argument\n");
        return 1;
    }
    // Putting all the argv letters into an array called key
    char key[26];
    memcpy(key, argv[1], 26);
    
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext: ");
    int len = strlen(plaintext);
    
    // Define an array called ciphertext, the length of the inputted text, to hold ciphertext chars and a null terminator
    char ciphertext[len + 1];
    
    // Looping through the inputted text, checking for upper and lower case letters
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        unsigned char c = plaintext[i];

        if (islower(c)) {        // The letter is lower case
            int index = c - 'a'; // Converting from ascii to decimal value and getting it into alphabetical index (0-25)
            ciphertext[i] = tolower((unsigned char)key[index]);
        } else
        if (isupper(c)) {
            // The letter is uppercase
            int index = c - 'A'; // Converting from ascii to decimal value and getting it into alphabetical index (0-25)
            ciphertext[i] = toupper((unsigned char)key[index]);
        } else {
            // other characters are unchanged
            ciphertext[i] = c;
        }
    }
    ciphertext[len] = '\0';  // set the null terminator

    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
    return 0;
}
```